# Is onScrollBeginDrag available on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I see that this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55940600/4480180) one, but there is no answer at the moment.

This what I tried:

```
<FlatList
onScrollBeginDrag={() => console.log("begin")}
onScrollEndDrag={() => console.log("end")}
...
>
```

This works correctly on iOS, but nothing happens on Android. However, I can't find anything about it on the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscrollbegindrag).

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same <s>shit</s> issue. After an enormous amount of debugging efforts, I finally figured it out!

It is caused by the `<View />` containing your `<FlatList />` items **being optimized away by Android**. Android automatically removes 'wrapping' views that do not actually render any content, such as a background color or borders. This optimization helps to reduce the depth of the view hierarchy but can cause unexpected results in some cases (such as this)...

I've added a transparent `backgroundColor` to the wrapping `<View />` of the items and now the `onScrollBeginDrag` and the `onScrollEndDrag` events of the `<FlatList />` are firing as expected!

```
<FlatList
  onScrollBeginDrag={() => console.log('begin')}
  onScrollEndDrag={() => console.log('end')}
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}

  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
      <Text>{item.key}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

I also removed the FlatList paddings and I added some paddings to the wrapping view, which makes the touchable area larger.

PS: Kudos to [Bartol Karuza](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22251#issuecomment-438524264).